# jQuery form validation plugin, error container div placement

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

While trying the bassistance.de's jQuery form validation plugin I ran into something interesting.

If I provide an `errorPlacement` option to append errors in a `<div id="errContainer"></div>` and place this *div* outside the `<form>`, the error messages are duplicated each time a validation occurs. Whereas, if the *errContainer div* is placed **inside** the `<form>`, things work just fine.

Example HTML:

```
<form id="frmQuote" action="#" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="txtQuote"/>
   <button type="submit" id="btn">Send</button>
</form>
<div id="errContainer"></div>
```

plugin option:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        error.appendTo($("#errContainer")); 
    }
//... further options
```

For this case, the errors duplicate as and when an element is validated. If I submit the form, the whole bunch of errors is displayed again, below the previous errors.

Is the placement of the *div* a dependency? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: could you please expand your question? Some code would be great. Also the div isn't a dependency, so something is going wrong with your implementation.

Comment: @StrouMfios: The exact code provided in the question was used which gave troubles. The scenario works perfectly fine just by moving the div outside the form. If the implementation was problematic, movement of div should not have cleared the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `errorPlacement` in this case, you should use the `errorLabelContainer`, which would do exactly what you are wanting, and also manage the errors correctly (i.e. not duplicate them):

```
$('#my-form').validate({
   //other options, rules, etc
   errorLabelContainer:'#errContainer'
});
```